# cannot be cast to android.widget.Filterable in Xamarin

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hai friends i am new to android and xamarin tool also I am working on **AutoCompleteTextView** with custom listview but i am getting an error in

```
  AssignedTo.Adapter = ssadapter ;
```

Please help me How can implement autocompletetext to hit the api and display the results in my list when am i search.   Here are my code

```
private void AssignedTo_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Text.Count()>=1)
        { 
          List<FilterObject> items = new List<FilterObject>();

            string data = LoginActivity.GetData("http://" + LoginActivity.IPAddress + "/SampleTest/api/MyTasks/GetUserList?text=" + e.Text + "");
            JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(data);
            if (obj.Length() > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject ex = obj.GetJSONObject(i);
                   items.Add(new FilterObject( ex.GetString("Value"),ex.GetString("Text")));

                }
            }
            FilterAdapter ssadapter = new FilterAdapter(this, items);

            AssignedTo.Adapter = ssadapter ;
}
```

and my class is

```
 public class FilterAdapter : BaseAdapter<FilterObject>
{

    public List<FilterObject> items;
    private Activity context;

    public FilterAdapter(Activity context, List<FilterObject> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override FilterObject this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SearchList_LayOut, null);

        TextView name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.name);
        name.Text = items[position].name;
        TextView id = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.id);
        id.Text = items[position].id;
        return view;
    }       

}

 public class FilterObject : System.Object
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }

public FilterObject(string id, string name)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `AssignedTo`?

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView AssignedTo;